# Check if IP first octect does not starts with 127 / 224 or 255

Tags: c++, ip

I have an IP stored in uint32_t type variable:

```
u32int_t ip = 4289172904;
```

I need to find if the first octet or IP does not starts with **127 / 224 and 225** address.

I am not sure how to achieve the same?

Comment: If you have an `int` that contains a three digit number, how do you check if the first digit is 1?

Comment: Extract first byte, then check value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on what you call the first octet

```
uint8_t octet = ip & 0xff;
```

or

```
uint8_t octet = (ip >> 24);
```

explaination for first solution:

`uint32_t` are on 32 bits

`0xff` is `00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111` in binary

so doing `ip & 0xff` will mask all bits that aren't from the lowest byte

Comment: Should be ff00 of just ff  as it is 32 bits?

Comment: @Programmer, 0xff is one byte, like an octet. 0xff00 would be the second-to-last byte, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense as the first octet.

Comment: Please clarify - it will not AND with last 16 bits of ip variable? Is it that in memory it would be arranged byte4, byte3 , byte 2 and then byte0?

Comment: @Programmer get pen and paper, draw. This always works for me.

Comment: @Programmer, You haven't told us how it's stored. The answer assumes the first octet is in the last byte.

Comment: You need to mention network/host byte order conundrum for this answer to be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

No detailed information about the semantics of your `uint32_t ip`. Be aware of the your host byte order (endian mode) may differ from network byte order. If necessary, uses `htonl(ip)` to convert to network byte order then uses bit wise operator to check the highest byte, e.g. `((htonl(ip) >> 24) & 0xff)` can get the first octet, then compares it against your 127/244/255, etc.